# Spamming with email notifications

Tags: support, notifications, spam, email

How come when asking a question and checking notifications checkbox you can enter any email in the text field nearby? Doesn't it mean that I can write any email of other SO user (or generally any email) to simply spam another person? Are there any counter measures against that?

Comment: There's only one way to find out.

Comment: I've never had SO send me an email, but I'd hope they'd have a "Stop receiving emails from StackOverflow.com" link in them.

Answer (score 6):

The funny thing is that every hapless user you do that to, has the ability to turn off all *your* email notifications with a single click.

(the link is included in every email that goes out).

So you'd have to go in and re-tick the global email notifications box every day for this sort of griefing to work. You'd almost be griefing yourself, really.

Answer (score 2):

In a way, I kind of like it and I wish it was easier for others to say "hey, here's a question I think you can answer" and have it sent to me (either through the SO UI or via email). On the other hand, it's far, far too open to abuse if you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that this would fall under the banner of objectionable behaviour (aka the [Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)).