# When you use the notify email feature, why does it over-write the main email?

Tags: discussion, notifications, email, sign-up

I'm registered on the trilogy sites using a personal email address, which will be mine forever and which has a gravatar associated with it.

Right now though, I'm at work, with limited access to my personal email (via phone only).

I've just asked a question about something at work, and I'd like notifications to come to my work email, but when I enter the work email address in the notify textbox, it over-writes the personal email I used when registering.

Is it possible to use a separate email for the notifications? If not, why not? It's a bit of a jump to assume that you want to change your email, especially as this causes the gravatar to disappear.

Comment: At least a warning would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

A warning would be nice; but think about the fact that if you could put anyone's email address in there, you could do some serious spam damage; or at least annoy another user.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27059/spamming-with-email-notifications

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this too when I posted a question that was relevant to work, so I plugged in my work email.

Then my gravatar stopped working; it took me a while to care/notice that my profile email had been updated and because gravatar didn't know about my work email, it wasn't serving up the correct image.

Obviously you can associate your work email with the gravatar, but should the email notification have such unexpected side-effects?