# E-mail notification change modifies my attached e-mail address

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When you use the notify email feature, why does it over-write the main email?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27747/when-you-use-the-notify-email-feature-why-does-it-over-write-the-main-email)

My SO account is setup from home, but I was at work and had a question.  I checked the notify box and put in my work e-mail address, so I'd get notification there, rather than at home.  Much to my surprise, my avatar suddenly changed.  Went into my settings and SO had changed my saved e-mail address to be the one I just put in for notifications!  This is not at all what I intended.  Seems to violate POLA (Principle Of Least Astonishment).  I just want the notification for that particular item to go to a specific e-mail address without breaking my default configuration.  There's nothing on the screen to suggest that I'm actually going to break my saved settings!

I'd like it if notification could be to a different address than saved, but I understand if that's not a reasonable request.  All I really care about is that UI changes be made to avoid POLA errors!  :-)

Thanks!

Comment: This is a dupe but I'm darned if I can find the original post where this was documented.

Comment: And here we go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27747/when-you-use-the-notify-email-feature-why-does-it-over-write-the-main-email